# Extra/Inter-polate from a Model

Tags: r, interpolation, lm, extrapolation

I managed to get some regression done using

```
lm(d$result~d$param1+d$param2) -> model
```

Now I would like to use `model` to extrapolate (or interpolate) the result
for a new dataframe. How can I do it ? I'm sure there is already a function for that.

Comment: Use command "predict" to predict using "model" on new data.

Comment: Lookup `?predict.lm`.  If `dat` is a data frame with new data, `predict(model, newdata = dat)`

Comment: @mb14 Sure thing.  Glad this was helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lookup `?predict.lm`.

If `dat` is a data frame with new data, `predict(model, newdata = dat)`